# Page formatting error in bluej

Tags: printing

When I print a program in blueJ, even if I set page to A4 size.All the program comes out in a weird small box. The same goes when I try to print any output of any program. Its the same box of the same size no matter what format i set the page to...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys I solved the problem temporarily though.
I installed cups-PDF. And it worked. But when I upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 and jdk 8 they same problem persists and can't be solved using the above method.